# array of pointer game not sure how to move pointers to back

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

there is a game that this program needs to play X-boom its supposed to take out the x player each turn and put it in the back of the array and then shorten the array so its no longer a part of it in that function. for example

player 1 2 3 4 and the x for the game is 3

players remaining: 1 2 4

players remaining: 1 4

players remaining: 1

i made this code that i think should do it but im not sure why its not working properly

i have a photo to how the output is supposed to look like but i dont know how to share it here if any one knows please tell me in the comments 
my problem is mostly with the play function notice that is number 3 in the array was kicked you are supposed to keep on playing from number 3 just that there will be a new pointer there

i tried to solve this be just going to the one that needed to be kicked and doing a swap for it to go back while moving everyone else forward and then shortening the array by 1

in the end the main function will print the array and it needs to be in order that the first player to be kicked will be last in the array

```
void get_boom_number(int * i){
    printf("enter the boom number\n");
    scanf("%d",i);
    return ;
}
#define LENGTH 31

void play(char * players[],int length,int boomnum){
    int count=-1;
     count = (count+boomnum-1)%(length);
    char * temp;
    for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",count);
        for (int start=count; start<length-1; start++) {
            temp=*(players+start);
            *(players+start)=*(players+start+1);
            *(players+start+1)=temp;
        }
        count=(count+boomnum-1)%(length);
        length=length-1;
    }
    return ;
}
int main()
{
    char * players[LENGTH]={"Tyrion Lannister","Daenerys Targaryen","Jon Snow","Arya Stark","Theon Greyjoy", "Joffrey Baratheon","Khal Drogo","Ted Mosby","Marshall Eriksen","Robin Scherbatsky","Barney Stinson", "Lily Aldrin", "Tracy McConnell", "Ted Mosby", "Leonard Hofstadter","Sheldon Cooper", "Penny", "Howard Wolowitz", "Raj Koothrappali", "Bernadette Rostenkowski-Wolowitz","Amy Farrah Fowler", "Gregory House", "Lisa Cuddy", "James Wilson","Eric Foreman", "Allison Cameron", "Robert Chase" ,"Lawrence Kutner", "Chris Taub","Remy 13 Hadley", "Amber Volakis"};
    int boom_number, i;
    get_boom_number(&boom_number);
    play(players,LENGTH,boom_number);
```

and then just printing the array also we are not alowed to use "[]" for the hole thing.

Comment: Note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter (`p[i]`) is usually easier to read and understand (and also a couple or characters less to write). Please consider this when you do e.g. `*(players+start)`.

Comment: i know but we are supposed to practice her using pointers so these are the rules

Comment: Ah okay. I heard of such assignments before, but in my opinion it's just stupid to add that requirement. The variable `players` is a pointer, what syntax you choose to use for dereferencing it should not matter. Pointer dereference is pointer dereference either way.

Comment: `int count=9;` I don't get why you start from 9. Can you explain

Comment: yes i realize that and if any of you want to use that form of writing if your solutions theres no problem i dont care its just my teacher

Comment: Also I don't understand this `for (int i = 0; i<30; i++)` Why do you want to execute the inner part 30 times?

Comment: oh sorry i didnt change that but as i said i was checking for x = 10 and at some point i just changed it to 9 since it would be the first any way but ill update the question

Comment: because the size of the array is 31 and it will take 30 turns for there to be one remaining player

Comment: That's a bad idea to have a fixed number of players. The code should automatically find out when there is only one player left!

Comment: yes and it will be fairly simple to do but the name library if this assessment wont change

Comment: how is LENGTH defined? Like `#define LENGTH 31` ?

Comment: yes that how why?

Comment: Because that info is need in order to compile the code. Please edit the question and add it.

Comment: right sorry i did

Comment: If the selected number shall be removed from the array, why do you swap neighbor cells? You can just assign in `players[x] = players[x+1]`. No need to bother about initial `players[x]` as it will be swapped again and again to the next position until it reaches the end of the array and will be dropped.

Comment: because i need to move all the rest of the players one move forward how else will i do it

Comment: i am not really removing it from the array just shortening the length of the array in this function, and forgot to write it down but later the main function will print the array and it needs to be in order that the first player to be kicked will be last in the array

Comment: read about `memmove()` for shortening the array @מכביחיפה

Comment: regarding: `char * players[LENGTH]={..};  This violates the premise that the '[]' is not to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your code is that `count` will become negative if the `boomnum` number is e.g. 1. I don't understand why `count` is initialized to -1 and why you subtract 1 more when recalculating `count`. Your code is the same as:

```
int count = (boomnum-2)%(length);
```

Again, it seems strange to subtract 2. Anyway, you must check that the result isn't negative.

Another problem is this:

```
    count=(count+boomnum-1)%(length);
    length=length-1;
```

This can cause `count` to be equal to `length` in the next iteration. I guess that's not what you want. You need to swap the two lines to avoid that. Like:

```
    length=length-1;
    count=(count+boomnum-1)%(length);
```

Doing that and input 2 for `boom_number` leads to the result:

```
Remy 13 Hadley
```

(Strange name by the way).

I would also change:

```
for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) {
```

to

```
while(length > 1) {
```

It's a bad idea to hard code the number of loops.

Further, this line:

```
count=(count+boomnum-1)%(length);
```

is also a problem. If `boomnum` is zero it may again cause `count` to become negative.

Comment: honestly im really confused by this code and if you can tell me what will work and we it would be great